# Single NavHost with BottomBar and Sign Page in Android Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to handle Single NavHost in Single Activity approach in Multi Module structure in Android Jetpack compose.

Did not see any example with below scenario to handle single NavHost in Single Activity.
Navigation should start from splash screen.

Custom Splash Screen -> Sign in Screen -> Home Screen with BottomBar

```
 NavHost(navController, startDestination = "Splash")
    {
        composable(route = "Splash") {
            Splash()
        }
        composable(route = "Sign In") {
            SignIn()
        }
        composable(route = "Home") {
            Home()
        }
}
```

BottomBar has 3 options to navigate between each bottom bar items.

Where to add BottomBar in above scenario?

**Updated as per comments**

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }) {
    // sub graph for Home?

}
```

Comment: In the Scaffold? If you're using one, that is.

Comment: In Which Screen, BottomBar logic can add, i need to show BottomBar after Navigating to Home Screen only..But NavHost declaration is there in Splash screen

Comment: If you have `Scaffold` in each composable, you can add bottombar only in `Home`. If you are using a single `Scaffold` for all three composable, you can show/hide the bottom bar conditionally based on the route.

Comment: I am using Scaffold for only in Home..updated code above...in that case, we have to use sub graph for Home?